# Probability of $3$ sticks forming a triangle - is my reasoning correct?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

**Foreword**: unlike many questions, this one asks not for the solution or hints, but for verification whether the reasoning is correct.

**Problem**: We randomly and uniformly choose three sticks, so that each length is no longer than $L$. What is the probability that these 3 sticks can form a triangle?

**Solution**: let's find the probability of the complement: They *cannot* form a triangle. It will happen if $l_1+l_2<l_3$, where $l_i$ is the length of stick number $1,2$ of $3$.

We know that $l_1+l_2\in[0,2L]$ and $l_3\in[0,L]$, so the probability that on a segment $[0,2L]$ we choose a point whose coordinate will be less than $L$ is $0.5$, thus, the probability that we cannot form a triangle is $0.5$ and that the complimentary probability is $1-0.5=0.5$

The book says this answer is correct, but it suggests using a 3D-coordinate solution with 3 inequalities and I'm afraid a bit I 'got lucky' getting the same answer.

Comment: This argument is not correct as we can find ratios $l_1 = 0.3L, l_2 =  0.3L, l_3 =  0.5L$, here $l_1 +l_2 < L$ and it will form a triangle.

Comment: In addition to what hunch wrote, you seem to be assuming that $l_3$ is the longest stick. This is fine, as you can simply relabel the sticks that way. However, that means that $l_1$ and $l_2$ are no longer arbitrary length sticks, but are instead the two shortest sticks. They are no longer uniformly distributed, as they are far less likely to be near $L$ than near $0$. It is therefore no longer the case that their sum has a $0.5$ probability of being less than L.